# Multiple scopes - WebAPI Spotify (Spotipy)

Tags: spotify, spotipy

My question is:
is possible using two or more scopes in the same time with WebAPI Spotify (in particular Spotipy)?
For example to use the scopes 'user-modify-playback-state' and 'user-library-read'

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can use multiple scopes when accessing the Spotify API. I've not worked directly with `Spotipy` but if it's similar to the packages I've used you can do the following (for example):

```py
import sys
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

scope = 'user-library-read user-modify-playback-state'

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "Usage: %s username" % (sys.argv[0],)
    sys.exit()

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print track['name'] + ' - ' + track['artists'][0]['name']
else:
    print "Can't get token for", username
```

That example is taken from https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#authorized-requests and adapted for >1 scope.

Note: if your users are auth'd with a different scope then you will need to get them to re-auth your app in order to gain access to further scope via a new token/refresh token.

Comment: Thanks! Needed this.